# VB.NET Winforms/.Net Framework 4.5.2 ListViewBox Disable Background Color

Tags: .net, vb.net, listview, listviewitem

I have a project with VB.NET Winforms/.Net Framework 4.5.2 and I'm currently using ListViewBox to display certain information. It works great, however, when the window is disabled (I.E. I have a child window that disables the parent window for certain things) the ListViewBox background color is gray. This is the example to see what I mean:

[image: Top one is enabled, bottom is disabled]

As you can see the bottom image occurs when the window is disabled. I would like to prevent that light gray from happening but I don't know how to solve this. I heard of some things such as making the background color the actual color (Black in this case), which does work as a hack, but any items that are added override this anyways so it does not work.

Comment: I solved this by overriding the WM_ENABLE in WNCPROC (Since I don't disable just the listview itself this works, regardless and prevents clicking/etc still.

Then I override the OnEnabledChanged, and set my own colors when enabled vs disabled. 

Seems to work alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the event with WNDPROC on the control (A custom control, i.e. Public Class CustomListView Inherits ListView) to prevent the window from taking a enable/disable. Then you also have to override the OnEnableChanged so you can change your own colors. It seems like when you re-enable and go back to your original/default colors, it will refresh the custom colors as well, so it works out here. You can probably go more advanced than this (Probably read-only) if you require it to be enabled/disabled individually, but because when you disable the whole form you still cannot interact with the ListView making this an OK solution for me without additional coding.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnEnabledChanged(e As System.EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnEnabledChanged(e)

    If Me.Enabled Then
        Me.ForeColor = Color.White
        Me.BackColor = Color.Black
    Else
        Me.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 200, 200, 200)
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 35, 35, 35)
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    Select Case m.Msg
        Case &HA 'WM_ENABLE
            ' Prevent the message from reaching the control,
            ' so the colors don't get changed by the default procedure.
            Exit Sub ' <-- suppress WM_ENABLE message
        Case Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
            Exit Select
    End Select
End Sub
```

This results in:
[image: End Result]

And because we change the forecolor back to normal, it refreshes the listview I presume, resulting in all the other colors going back to normal as the above image shows in my question.

It might not be pristine but I hope it helps someone start on the right direction.